# How to remove the horizontal line in a sphinx pdf documentation generated with rinohtype

Tags: python-sphinx, rinohtype

This is my current stylesheet:

```
[STYLESHEET]
name=MyStyle
base=sphinx

[object description]
label_max_width=10pt

[title page title]
typeface=$(sans_typeface)
font_size=20pt
font_color=#000
text_align=right
space_above=0pt

[title page author]
hide=true
typeface=$(sans_typeface)
font_weight=bold
font_size=17pt
text_align=right
space_above=110pt
```

I've been looking into how to remove that horizontal line in the title page or at least change its color, and it's not very well documented. Has anyone ever been able to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the *title page rule* style, which is listed in the [Style Sheets](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/stylesheets.html#default-matcher) documentation section.

To hide this line, set its *hide* property:

```ini
[title page rule]
hide = true
```

In general, you can discover which style definition you need to tweak by examining the [style log](http://www.mos6581.org/rinohtype/master/elementstyling.html#style-logs) which logs which style is applied to each of the document elements. For the title page, the log will look similar to this:

```
---------------------------------- page 1 ----------------------------------
#### FlowablesContainer('background')
  StaticGroupedFlowables()
#### DownExpandingContainer('title')
  StaticGroupedFlowables()
    HorizontalRule(style='title page rule')
         > (0,0,1,0,2) title page rule [Sphinx] > DEFAULT
           (0,0,0,0,2) horizontal rule [Sphinx] > DEFAULT
    Image('/some/path/to/logo.png', style='title page logo')
         > (0,0,1,0,2) title page logo [Sphinx] > DEFAULT
           (0,0,0,0,2) image [Sphinx] > DEFAULT
    Paragraph('References', style='title page title')
         > (0,0,1,0,2) title page title [Sphinx] > DEFAULT
           (0,0,0,0,2) body [Sphinx] > default
        SingleStyledText('References')
    Paragraph('Release ', style='title page subtitle')
         > (0,0,1,0,2) title page subtitle [Sphinx] > title page title
           (0,0,0,0,2) body [Sphinx] > default
        SingleStyledText('Release ')
    Paragraph('Author', style='title page author')
         > (0,0,1,0,2) title page author [Sphinx] > DEFAULT
           (0,0,0,0,2) body [Sphinx] > default
        SingleStyledText('Author')
```

The `>` at the start of a line indicates which style is chosen.

The user experience could be improved upon, but this should go a long way to help development of a style sheet.